# Cutting off SVG path shows background color

Tags: svg, path, background-color, transparent

I'm not well experienced in SVG but trying to make all paths transparent.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 1064.9733" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(1.333333, 0, 0, -1.333333, 0, 1064.973282)" id="g10">
    <g transform="scale(0.1)" id="g12">
      <path id="path16" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3372.58,4594.11 c -1.4,-1.3 -6.7,-6.6 -11.2,-16.4 h -0.1 c -2,-0.2 -3.9,-0.5 -5.8,-0.9 7.8,9.5 15.2,15.8 17.1,17.3"/>
      <path id="path18" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 5435.38,4525.51 c 0,0 -161.8,27.5 -413.9,54.1 -20,2.1 -40.6,4.2 -61.8,6.3 -38.7,3.9 -79.3,7.6 -121.4,11.2 -34.9,3 -71,5.9 -108,8.7 -21.4,1.5 -43.2,3.1 -65.3,4.6 -19.7,1.3 -39.6,2.6 -59.9,3.8 -0.1,-0.1 -0.3,-0.1 -0.4,0 -6.4,0.4 -12.9,0.7 -19.4,1.1 -8.7,0.8 -15.6,1.1 -21.7,1.3 -0.8,0 -1.7,0.1 -2.5,0.1 -0.9,0 -1.8,0.1 -2.7,0.1 -0.4,0 -0.7,0 -1,0.1 -11.5,0.6 -23.2,1.2 -34.9,1.8 h -0.4 c -142.4,7.2 -294.1,11.3 -449.4,9.9 -9.5,0 -19,-0.1 -28.5,-0.2 -66.3,-0.9 -133.1,-2.7 -200.1,-5.8 -162.1,-7.2 -325.1,-21.4 -482.7,-44.9 4.5,9.8 9.8,15.1 11.2,16.4 -1.9,-1.5 -9.3,-7.8 -17.1,-17.3 h -0.1 c -405.3,-61 -774.4,-184 -1001.5,-411.1 -129.2,-129.2 -138.4,-618.2 1033.3,-1494.7 v -239.8 l -178.3,286 -412.1,286 175.2,-249.1 -230.6,166.1 -156.9,-138.4 101.5,286 -369,-424.4 -120,-719.7 -73.8,313.7 -55.3,-276.8 -369.1,378.3 221.5,-594.1 -489,372.7 -448.999,-372.7 c 0,0 15.301,529.5 1688.399,1427.5 0,0 -953.4,688.9 -261.5,1270.2 195.6,164.2 456,276.2 747.7,342.7 40.4,9.2 81.4,17.5 122.9,25 155.6,28.1 318.4,44.1 483.7,49.2 h 0.1 c 216.9,6.6 438,-5.8 652.9,-35.1 378.5,-51.3 737.4,-154.9 1018.9,-298.8"/>
      <path id="path20" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 4585.28,4615.31 c -7.2,0.4 -14.4,0.9 -21.7,1.3 6.1,-0.2 13,-0.5 21.7,-1.3"/>
      <path id="path22" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 4706.58,5577.31 c -143,92.3 -263,-4.6 -309.1,-41.5 -33.2,-26.6 701.2,-650.5 701.2,-650.5 0,0 -513.4,283.45 -675.7,385.3 -0.1,0 -48.4,32.5 -76.2,48.4 -161.5,92.2 -498.3,182.9 -604.4,146.8 -106.1,-36.1 -359.8,-294.5 -387.5,-345.2 -26,-47.8 160.8,190.9 390.7,157 6.1,-0.8 12.1,-1.9 18.2,-3.1 8.2,-1.8 16.5,-3.8 24.8,-6.3 10.9,-3.2 21.3,-6.5 31.3,-9.9 219,-73.1 236.7,-172.2 448.4,-220.7 8.9,-2 17.6,-4 26.3,-5.8 207.9,-45 356.6,-45 356.6,-45 0,0 -110.9,-13.4 -279.9,4.3 -111.1,11.7 -247.2,36.8 -393.6,88 -78.9,27.6 -153.1,40.1 -222.1,42.1 -194.5,5.7 -346.8,-71.4 -441.5,-124 -9,-5 -17.4,-9.7 -25.3,-14.2 -17.5,-9.8 -32.4,-18.1 -44.6,-23.9 -12.3,-5.9 -27.7,-11.1 -45.4,-15.8 -22.3,-6 -48.1,-11.1 -75.3,-15.4 -121.3,-19.4 -271.4,-24.1 -271.4,-24.1 0,0 -181.2,19.1 -405.7,-332 6.7,14.6 371.8,797 691.7,1190 322.9,396.7 636.6,645.9 839.6,590.5 203,-55.4 573.3,-249.9 1227.1,-1356.3 119.9,-202.9 -355.2,489 -498.2,581.3"/>
      <path id="path24" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 5619.95,4331.77 c 0,0 410.56,-387.5 -207.59,-991.82 0,0 655.06,-548.95 871.87,-678.12 216.82,-129.17 715.04,-533.21 733.49,-917.05 0,0 -129.17,312.73 -207.59,317.35 -78.42,4.61 -198.36,-179.91 -198.36,-179.91 0,0 32.29,138.39 32.29,198.36 0,59.97 -27.68,193.75 -69.2,156.84 -41.52,-36.9 -55.36,-115.32 -55.36,-115.32 l -170.68,-276.79 c 0,0 46.13,216.82 73.81,286.01 27.68,69.2 83.03,184.53 83.03,184.53 0,0 -281.4,-249.11 -350.59,-322.92 -69.2,-73.81 59.97,202.98 59.97,202.98 0,0 212.2,179.91 212.2,193.75 0,13.84 -133.78,23.06 -133.78,23.06 0,0 9.23,129.17 -78.42,138.39 -87.65,9.23 -18.45,46.14 -119.94,101.49 -101.49,55.36 -230.66,59.97 -359.82,-59.97 -129.17,-119.94 -433.64,-341.37 -433.64,-341.37 0,0 239.89,235.27 313.7,341.37 73.81,106.1 161.45,138.4 115.32,226.04 -46.13,87.65 -64.58,235.27 -179.91,244.5 -115.33,9.22 -138.39,87.65 -189.13,110.71 -50.75,23.07 -110.72,147.62 -101.49,161.46 9.22,13.84 655.06,378.28 359.82,996.43"/>
      <path id="path26" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 5017.28,4368.91 c -9.8,-114.3 -98.4,-267.7 -106.3,-339.6 -8,-71.8 -34.1,-189.4 -57,-225.3 -22.9,-35.9 -29.4,-68.6 -29.4,-81.7 0,-13 -62,-88.1 -91.4,-150.2 -29.4,-62 -55.1,-68.6 -47.2,-169.8 8,-101.2 -139,-362.5 -139,-362.5 0,0 -81.6,-104.5 -88.2,-160 -6.5,-55.5 -35.9,-127.4 -35.9,-127.4 0,0 -88.2,55.5 -91.4,71.9 -3.3,16.3 -55.5,26.1 -55.5,75.1 0,49 45.7,143.7 45.7,143.7 0,0 -71.9,-42.5 -130.6,-62.1 -58.8,-19.6 -228.6,-55.5 -228.6,-55.5 0,0 -58.8,-35.9 -71.9,9.8 -13,45.7 -26.1,58.8 -29.4,84.9 -3.2,26.1 -39.2,26.1 0,55.5 39.2,29.4 13.1,16.4 22.9,52.3 9.8,35.9 19.6,32.6 26.1,58.8 6.5,26.1 0,94.7 0,94.7 0,0 -29.4,91.4 -19.6,111 9.8,19.6 16.3,133.9 19.6,163.3 3.3,29.4 3.3,163.3 0,202.5 -3.3,39.1 -9.8,173 0,199.2 9.8,26.1 9.8,91.4 0,120.8 -9.8,29.4 -19.6,127.4 -19.6,140.4 0,13.1 3.3,81.7 -3.2,91.5 -6.6,9.8 6.5,94.7 6.5,104.5 0,9.8 6.5,71.8 -22.9,71.8 -14.3,0 -21.6,19.2 -26.9,46.1 67,3.1 133.8,4.9 200.1,5.8 9.5,0.1 19,0.2 28.5,0.2 155.3,1.4 307,-2.7 449.4,-9.9 h 0.4 c 13.7,-1.7 22.4,-1.6 34.9,-1.8 0.3,-0.1 0.6,-0.1 1,-0.1 0.9,0 1.8,-0.1 2.7,-0.1 0.8,0 1.7,-0.1 2.5,-0.1 6.1,-0.2 13,-0.5 21.7,-1.3 2.5,-0.2 5.2,-0.4 8.1,-0.7 4.3,-0.4 8.1,-0.5 11.3,-0.4 0.1,-0.1 0.3,-0.1 0.4,0 31.1,1 18,23.2 47.5,33.1 32.7,10.8 45.7,-6.6 45.7,-6.6 0,0 -20,-8.5 -33.3,-30.3 -3.2,-5.1 -5.9,-11 -8,-17.6 -10.9,-34.8 -28.3,-78.3 -34.9,-126.2 -6.5,-47.9 -63.1,-78.4 -75.1,-115.4 -12,-37 -40.3,13 -40.3,65.3 0,52.2 26.2,82.7 8.7,117.6 -17.4,34.8 -65.3,74 -65.3,74 0,0 15.3,-58.8 4.4,-124.1 -10.9,-65.3 -39.2,-132.8 -4.4,-178.5 34.9,-45.8 100.2,-80.6 80.6,-124.1 -19.6,-43.6 -58.8,-61 -82.7,-58.8 -24,2.2 -75.7,-4.4 -52,-61 23.7,-56.6 38.9,-56.6 54.1,-60.9 15.3,-4.4 -8.7,-43.6 2.2,-61 10.9,-17.4 21.8,-54.4 15.3,-65.3 -6.6,-10.9 0,-15.3 37,50.1 37,65.3 79.7,41.3 88.8,104.5 9.1,63.1 12.4,128.4 17.3,148 4.9,19.6 -9.3,6.5 29.4,2.2 38.6,-4.4 103.8,-2.2 121.3,15.2 17.5,17.4 -15.2,28.3 -36.9,132.8 -21.8,104.5 -47.9,202.5 -13.1,254.8 5.1,7.7 11.6,15.7 18.9,23.8 37,-2.8 73.1,-5.7 108,-8.7 -4.2,-30.9 -11.4,-61.2 -23.5,-79.4 -32.7,-49 0,-192.6 0,-192.6 0,0 62.1,45.7 84.9,143.6 10.4,44.5 35.6,85.6 60,117.2 21.2,-2.1 41.8,-4.2 61.8,-6.3 0.6,-31.5 -0.1,-72.7 -4.2,-120.7"/>
      <path id="path28" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 4305.29,2840.62 c 4.6,3.64 6.58,-66.95 19.64,-88.18 13.07,-21.22 29.84,-29.39 51.66,-24.49 21.82,4.9 39.78,11.43 39.78,11.43 0,0 12.88,-29.39 -16.42,-66.94 -29.3,-37.56 -43.99,-27.76 -65.22,-101.24 -21.23,-73.48 -70.21,-164.92 -80.01,-209 -9.79,-44.09 -24.49,-111.04 -88.17,-120.83 -63.68,-9.8 -150.22,-4.9 -177.98,22.86 -27.76,27.75 -31.02,68.58 -78.38,50.61 -47.35,-17.96 -42.45,-31.02 -117.56,-62.04 -75.11,-31.03 -127.36,-50.09 -169.82,-16.07 -42.45,34.03 -89.8,96.08 -89.8,132 0,35.92 17.96,52.25 0,70.21 -17.96,17.96 -37.56,40.82 -32.66,52.25 4.9,11.43 81.64,68.58 127.36,78.38 45.72,9.79 93.07,-4.9 161.65,29.39 68.58,34.29 124.1,39.19 129,42.45 4.9,3.27 4.9,24.49 -34.29,29.39 -39.19,4.9 -73.48,4.9 -119.2,-26.12 -45.72,-31.03 -53.88,-42.46 -88.17,-47.36 -34.29,-4.89 -94.71,-26.12 -94.71,-26.12 0,0 0,13.06 76.75,53.88 76.74,40.82 171.44,73.48 204.1,73.48 32.66,0 73.89,26.13 81.03,26.13 7.14,0 99.78,-16.33 150.62,-44.09 50.83,-27.76 70.43,-47.35 129.21,-58.78 58.78,-11.43 91.07,11.43 96.15,21.22 5.08,9.8 14.79,32.66 -14.56,27.76 -29.34,-4.9 -63.63,-35.92 -60.36,-9.79 3.26,26.12 19.49,147.26 60.36,179.61"/>
      <path id="path30" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3949.93,2909.74 c -7.6,0.85 -3.81,-38.64 0,-52.79 3.81,-14.15 5.44,-27.49 34.83,-16.2 29.39,11.3 56.6,34.16 63.14,40.69 6.53,6.53 6.53,25.58 6.53,34.29 0,8.71 0,21.77 0,21.77 0,0 -89.81,-29.39 -104.5,-27.76"/>
      <path id="path32" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 4086,2945.66 c -4.53,1.09 -20.69,-3.26 -20.69,-11.97 0,-8.71 -3.81,-37.3 5.99,-46.68 9.8,-9.38 40.28,-14.82 58.78,-5.57 18.51,9.25 41.37,37.01 43.54,43.54 2.18,6.53 -2.72,41.91 -2.72,41.91 0,0 -68.99,-25.05 -84.9,-21.23"/>
      <path id="path34" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3950.2,2826.74 c 0,-2.86 -8.91,-42.45 -4.66,-51.84 4.25,-9.39 35.68,-16.33 47.11,-20.01 11.43,-3.67 34.29,-23.26 37.15,-19.18 2.86,4.08 0.41,18.37 11.84,31.43 11.43,13.06 22.45,36.33 19.59,42.45 -2.86,6.13 5.31,16.74 -13.47,19.6 -18.78,2.86 -22.86,2.45 -36.33,0 -13.47,-2.45 -61.23,-2.45 -61.23,-2.45"/>
      <path id="path36" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 4072.25,2823.88 c 2.04,1.23 7.35,9.36 22.45,12.64 15.11,3.28 21.23,4.07 33.07,0 11.84,-4.07 24.49,-5.7 25.31,-12.64 0.81,-6.94 -8.57,-23.27 -13.06,-35.92 -4.5,-12.66 -5.31,-32.25 -2.45,-40.82 2.85,-8.57 -12.66,-17.15 -22.46,-5.72 -9.79,11.43 -17.55,22.45 -22.45,36.74 -4.9,14.29 -5.3,21.64 -12.24,27.35 -6.94,5.72 -8.17,18.37 -8.17,18.37"/>
      <path id="path38" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3915.91,2831.18 c 0,0 -11.43,2.09 -5.72,-28.93 5.72,-31.03 9.8,-53.89 -7.34,-41.64 -17.15,12.25 -25.31,30.42 -47.36,22.56 -22.04,-7.87 -31.02,-15 -40.82,0 -9.79,14.99 -29.39,25.61 -21.22,37.04 8.16,11.43 19.59,23.64 44.08,16.31 24.49,-7.33 78.38,-5.34 78.38,-5.34"/>
      <path id="path40" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3861.21,2921.77 c -5.72,1.31 -35.11,2.94 -40.01,-9.31 -4.9,-12.24 -8.16,-32.65 7.35,-46.53 15.51,-13.88 22.04,-19.6 43.27,-19.6 21.23,0 42.46,-3.26 44.09,4.08 1.63,7.35 7.35,40.83 7.35,40.83 0,0 2.72,17.14 -12.93,17.14 -15.65,0 -49.12,13.39 -49.12,13.39"/>
      <path id="path42" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3662,2851.23 c 0,0 41.64,-8.71 65.32,-10.48 23.67,-1.77 17.96,3.85 17.96,-9.57 0,-13.42 2.02,-55.06 0.6,-59.96 -1.42,-4.9 -41.42,-23.67 -52.04,-18.78 -10.61,4.9 -30.21,5.82 -26.94,35.16 3.27,29.34 2.45,37.41 -1.63,43.58 -4.08,6.17 -3.27,20.05 -3.27,20.05"/>
      <path id="path44" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3704.16,2956.55 c -2.97,-0.82 -42.97,-8.98 -34.81,-29.39 8.16,-20.41 26.94,-36.25 53.88,-43.02 26.95,-6.78 40.82,-30.23 45.72,-7.48 4.9,22.74 13.07,23.54 -5.71,46 -18.78,22.46 -25.09,28.99 -32.55,33.89 -7.46,4.9 -26.53,0 -26.53,0"/>
      <path id="path46" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3624.45,2922.66 c -8.17,-10.2 -40.82,-70.43 -52.25,-77.05 -11.43,-6.63 -34.29,-26.22 -34.29,-26.22 0,0 29.39,-31.02 43.27,-55.52 13.88,-24.49 13.88,-57.14 0,-70.21 -13.88,-13.06 -61.24,-31.02 -72.67,-9.79 -11.43,21.22 -8.92,103.73 -8.92,103.73 0,0 -46.59,13.83 -49.86,23.63 -3.26,9.79 16.44,47.06 49.86,75.78 33.42,28.72 124.86,35.65 124.86,35.65"/>
      <path id="path48" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3436.67,2798.36 c -8.16,-3.46 -29.39,-41.21 -24.49,-41.11 4.9,0.09 44.08,-9.7 48.98,9.89 4.9,19.59 -24.49,31.22 -24.49,31.22"/>
      <path id="path50" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3679.96,3377.82 c 0,0 16.33,-44.08 34.29,-73.48 17.96,-29.39 25.15,-50.61 60.75,-68.57 35.59,-17.97 42.14,-56.68 42.14,-56.68 0,0 -75.72,45.25 -112.98,50.14 -37.26,4.9 -79.71,0 -79.71,0 0,0 -9.8,132.26 55.51,148.59"/>
      <path id="path52" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3759.97,3408.85 c 0,0 -28.32,58.78 -91.72,47.35 -63.4,-11.43 -146.67,-52.25 -151.57,-89.81 -4.9,-37.55 -29.39,-104.5 0,-142.05 29.39,-37.56 53.88,-70.22 65.31,-111.04 11.43,-40.82 101.24,-119.19 101.24,-119.19 0,0 -93.07,-3.27 -120.83,15.51 -27.76,18.77 -39.19,64.49 -48.99,100.42 -9.79,35.92 -30.09,124.09 -64.03,128.99 -33.94,4.9 -95.98,14.7 -123.74,29.39 -27.76,14.7 -71.85,17.96 -71.85,75.11 0,57.15 -11.43,173.08 11.43,205.74 22.86,32.66 117.39,63.68 171.36,26.13 53.97,-37.56 158.48,-13.07 158.48,-13.07 0,0 -56.75,-24.49 -89.61,-48.98 -32.86,-24.5 -43.74,-66.95 -43.74,-66.95 0,0 268.87,115.93 298.26,-37.55"/>
      <path id="path54" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3462.8,3704.39 c 0,0 8.16,-44.09 50.61,-44.09 42.46,0 58.79,35.93 58.79,44.09 0,8.16 63.68,8.16 81.64,16.33 17.96,8.16 70.21,55.51 91.44,62.05 21.22,6.53 44.13,101.23 71.86,128.99 27.74,27.76 62.03,50.62 62.03,50.62 0,0 -29.39,-39.19 -40.82,-80.01 -11.43,-40.82 -66.95,-126.84 -66.95,-126.84 0,0 75.11,-13.58 88.18,-54.41 13.06,-40.82 13.06,-148.58 19.59,-158.38 6.53,-9.8 -40.82,34.29 -45.72,65.31 -4.9,31.03 -17.96,60.42 -42.45,83.28 -24.5,22.86 -51.12,31.02 -70.47,26.12 -19.34,-4.9 -14.44,-17.96 -42.2,-52.25 -27.76,-34.29 -29.39,-53.88 -130.63,-57.15 -101.23,-3.26 -174.71,35.92 -146.95,84.91 27.76,48.99 62.05,11.43 62.05,11.43"/>
      <path id="path56" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3415.48,4241.61 c -36,-52.3 -89.8,-62.1 -96.4,-99.6 -6.5,-37.6 -6.5,-63.4 -9.8,-96.2 -3.2,-32.8 19.6,-107.9 19.6,-138.9 0,-31.1 -24.5,-99.7 -42.4,-58 -18,41.6 -7.4,105.3 -35.5,147.8 -28.2,42.4 -51.9,122.4 0,156.7 51.8,34.3 92.6,50.2 107.3,104.3 14.7,54.1 14.7,96.5 -16.3,147.2 -19.6,31.9 -2.1,63.2 13.4,81.9 h 0.1 c 7.8,9.5 15.2,15.8 17.1,17.3 -1.4,-1.3 -6.7,-6.6 -11.2,-16.4 h -0.1 c -8.4,-18.1 -14.3,-51.4 11.7,-102.4 42.5,-83.3 78.4,-91.5 42.5,-143.7"/>
      <path id="path58" style="fill:#ec1d27;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 3196.64,4440.8 c 6.53,-9.8 66.91,-52.25 23.66,-119.2 -43.25,-66.94 -71.01,-80.01 -97.14,-127.36 -26.12,-47.35 -9.79,-107.77 13.07,-117.56 22.86,-9.8 29.39,-37.56 24.49,-44.09 -4.9,-6.53 -60.41,-1.63 -84.91,26.13 -24.49,27.75 -80.01,36.72 -21.22,111.43 58.78,74.71 47.35,71.44 77.56,131.86 30.2,60.41 64.49,138.79 64.49,138.79"/>
      <path id="path60" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4961.74,4435.36 c 0,0 -15.24,-52.25 -15.24,-74.02 0,-21.78 -15.24,-67.5 -17.42,-93.62 -2.17,-26.13 -21.77,-67.49 -21.77,-67.49 0,0 41.37,19.59 54.43,58.78 13.06,39.19 -4.35,78.38 0,104.5 4.36,26.13 0,71.85 0,71.85"/>
      <path id="path62" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4135.52,2541.81 c 0.74,5.84 70.22,-4.9 83.28,-80.01 0,0 -88.17,40.82 -83.28,80.01"/>
      <path id="path64" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4738.04,3939.52 c 0,0 -31.02,-58.78 -53.88,-80.01 -22.86,-21.23 -44.09,-35.92 -78.38,-39.19 -34.29,-3.26 -81.64,-45.72 -101.23,-48.98 -19.6,-3.27 26.12,-27.76 76.74,0 50.62,27.75 50.62,13.06 88.17,39.18 37.56,26.13 78.38,73.48 68.58,129"/>
      <path id="path66" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4760.9,3828.49 c 0,16.32 -75.11,-231.87 -122.46,-292.28 0,0 122.46,130.62 122.46,292.28"/>
      <path id="path68" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4249.82,4045.78 c 0,0 -34.29,-45.85 -21.22,-80.14 13.06,-34.29 53.88,-75.11 66.94,-99.6 13.07,-24.49 13.07,-68.58 0,-96.34 -13.06,-27.75 -52.25,-52.25 -44.08,-60.41 8.16,-8.17 83.27,3.26 101.23,0 17.96,-3.27 58.78,-3 58.78,-3 0,0 -4.45,-39.46 -34.88,-47.62 -30.43,-8.16 -69.62,4.9 -79.41,9.8 -9.8,4.9 -40.83,7.82 -40.83,-12.42 0,-20.24 21.53,-67.59 62.2,-62.69 40.67,4.9 89.66,3.26 120.68,32.65 31.03,29.39 71.85,56.72 71.85,56.72 0,0 -16.33,-53.45 -17.96,-59.98 -1.64,-6.53 -9.8,-40.82 -76.75,-68.58 0,0 57.15,-8.17 107.77,83.27 50.62,91.44 155.12,120.8 155.12,120.8 0,0 11.43,-16.29 -11.43,-53.85 -22.86,-37.56 -50.62,-53.88 -81.64,-86.54 -31.03,-32.66 -46.83,-70.21 -86.28,-94.71 -39.45,-24.49 -135.79,-63.68 -166.81,-57.14 -31.03,6.53 -50.62,14.69 -83.28,14.69 -32.65,0 -68.58,-6.53 -63.68,24.49 4.9,31.03 44.09,45.72 65.32,45.72 21.22,0 35.92,8.17 16.33,22.86 -19.6,14.7 -55.52,21.23 -66.95,19.6 -11.43,-1.64 -29.39,9.79 -57.15,-3.27 -27.76,-13.06 -93.07,-53.88 -93.07,-53.88 0,0 13.06,58.78 21.22,71.84 8.17,13.07 53.89,42.46 53.89,42.46 0,0 -60.42,-9.8 -75.11,-42.46 0,0 11.43,109.4 55.51,132.26 0,0 -70.21,-35.92 -99.6,-146.95 -29.39,-111.04 -55.52,-104.51 -55.52,-104.51 0,0 40.83,68.58 27.76,143.7 -13.06,75.11 31.03,122.98 31.03,122.98 0,0 -58.79,-20.12 -58.79,-36.44 0,0 11.43,40.82 45.72,47.35 0,0 -47.35,6.44 -52.25,62.82 -4.9,56.37 21.23,142.92 21.23,142.92 0,0 40.82,-29.4 60.41,-81.65 19.6,-52.25 31.03,-101.23 50.62,-112.66 19.6,-11.43 89.81,-58.78 94.71,-66.95 4.9,-8.16 40.82,-14.69 40.82,-14.69 0,0 -13.06,45.72 19.59,71.84 32.66,26.13 47.35,48.95 24.49,80.81 -22.85,31.86 -102.86,134.99 -6.53,196.9"/>
      <path id="path70" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4096.34,3310.88 c 0,0 13.06,1.63 40.82,39.18 27.76,37.56 34.29,86.54 57.15,65.32 22.86,-21.23 55.51,-1.39 55.51,-49.68 0,-48.29 -22.86,-46.66 0,-76.05 22.86,-29.39 42.46,-50.62 42.46,-50.62 0,0 -3.27,-21.23 -21.23,-32.66 -17.96,-11.43 -27.76,9.8 -31.02,-16.32 -3.27,-26.13 -14.7,-63.69 -14.7,-63.69 0,0 14.7,-16.32 40.82,16.33 26.13,32.66 34.29,35.93 62.05,63.68 27.76,27.76 37.56,37.56 68.58,37.56 31.02,0 114.3,6.53 119.2,6.53 4.89,0 -138.79,-0.57 -155.12,20.94 -16.33,21.51 -30.41,99.89 -47.87,135.81 -17.45,35.93 -15.81,60.6 -66.43,58.06 -50.62,-2.54 -168.18,-31.93 -150.22,-154.39"/>
      <path id="path72" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4151.85,3501.92 c 0,0 -37.55,-60.42 -71.84,-96.34 -34.29,-35.92 -55.52,-122.46 -55.52,-122.46 0,0 -45.72,75.11 0,117.56 45.72,42.46 127.36,101.24 127.36,101.24"/>
      <path id="path74" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4244.93,3268.42 c 0,-4.9 -16.33,-52.25 -29.4,-71.84 -13.06,-19.6 -13.06,-35.93 -32.65,-66.95 -19.6,-31.02 -47.36,-55.52 -47.36,-27.76 0,27.76 11.43,53.2 22.86,77.22 11.43,24.02 24.5,45.25 39.19,48.51 14.7,3.27 47.36,40.82 47.36,40.82"/>
      <path id="path76" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4480.05,3167.19 c -4.89,0 -63.68,-34.29 -83.27,-52.25 -19.59,-17.97 -22.86,-4.9 -34.29,-71.85 -11.43,-66.95 -39.19,-93.07 -42.45,-106.13 -3.27,-13.07 37.55,-84.91 37.55,-84.91 0,0 -4.46,24.49 19,93.07 23.45,68.58 33.25,130.89 56.11,144.64 22.86,13.75 47.35,77.43 47.35,77.43"/>
      <path id="path78" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 3554.23,2447.1 c 8.6,11.11 40.83,55.52 62.05,42.46 21.23,-13.07 39.19,-44.96 57.15,-20.03 17.96,24.93 8.17,54.63 40.82,60.19 32.66,5.56 55.52,-21.13 83.28,13.44 27.76,34.57 83.27,44.37 91.44,32.94 8.16,-11.43 19.59,27.76 21.22,-24.49 1.64,-52.26 -11.43,-99.61 -32.65,-104.51 -21.23,-4.89 -70.22,6.54 -94.71,0 -24.49,-6.53 -4.9,24.5 -44.08,14.7 -39.19,-9.8 -63.69,-14.7 -102.87,-32.66 -39.19,-17.96 -68.58,-27.76 -68.58,-27.76 0,0 -24.86,30.48 -13.07,45.72"/>
      <path id="path80" style="fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" d="m 4160.48,3791.01 c -4.7,2.2 -156.3,76 -156.3,239.4 0,61 56.6,89.3 73.8,158.9 17.3,69.7 4.2,63.2 -24.1,185.1 -20.1,86.5 -26.8,121.5 -9.7,164 9.5,0.1 19,0.2 28.5,0.2 -12.8,-38.4 -32.4,-63.5 -7.9,-116.3 28.3,-61 78.4,-102.3 60.9,-172 -17.4,-69.7 -43.5,-89.3 -56.6,-163.3 -13,-74 -36.6,-84.9 8.9,-165.5 44.2,-78 80.3,-127.4 82.5,-130.5"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now when I make the paths from id 60 to 80 transparent, the background appears red. But I want to make them completely transparent. I can imagine that this is easy to do, but somewhere I have a stupid reasoning error.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've combined the d attributes of path 26, 28 and 60 to 80 in one path.

Also I've changed fill-rule:nonzero to evenodd and now paths 60 to 80 appear as holes.
In order to simplify the code I've removed the irrelevant paths.

```css
svg{background:gold;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 400 1066.6667 1064.9733" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(1.333333, 0, 0, -1.333333, 0, 1064.973282)" id="g10">
    <g transform="scale(0.1)" id="g12">

     
     
      <path id="path26" style="fill:blue;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" d="m 5017.28,4368.91 c -9.8,-114.3 -98.4,-267.7 -106.3,-339.6 -8,-71.8 -34.1,-189.4 -57,-225.3 -22.9,-35.9 -29.4,-68.6 -29.4,-81.7 0,-13 -62,-88.1 -91.4,-150.2 -29.4,-62 -55.1,-68.6 -47.2,-169.8 8,-101.2 -139,-362.5 -139,-362.5 0,0 -81.6,-104.5 -88.2,-160 -6.5,-55.5 -35.9,-127.4 -35.9,-127.4 0,0 -88.2,55.5 -91.4,71.9 -3.3,16.3 -55.5,26.1 -55.5,75.1 0,49 45.7,143.7 45.7,143.7 0,0 -71.9,-42.5 -130.6,-62.1 -58.8,-19.6 -228.6,-55.5 -228.6,-55.5 0,0 -58.8,-35.9 -71.9,9.8 -13,45.7 -26.1,58.8 -29.4,84.9 -3.2,26.1 -39.2,26.1 0,55.5 39.2,29.4 13.1,16.4 22.9,52.3 9.8,35.9 19.6,32.6 26.1,58.8 6.5,26.1 0,94.7 0,94.7 0,0 -29.4,91.4 -19.6,111 9.8,19.6 16.3,133.9 19.6,163.3 3.3,29.4 3.3,163.3 0,202.5 -3.3,39.1 -9.8,173 0,199.2 9.8,26.1 9.8,91.4 0,120.8 -9.8,29.4 -19.6,127.4 -19.6,140.4 0,13.1 3.3,81.7 -3.2,91.5 -6.6,9.8 6.5,94.7 6.5,104.5 0,9.8 6.5,71.8 -22.9,71.8 -14.3,0 -21.6,19.2 -26.9,46.1 67,3.1 133.8,4.9 200.1,5.8 9.5,0.1 19,0.2 28.5,0.2 155.3,1.4 307,-2.7 449.4,-9.9 h 0.4 c 13.7,-1.7 22.4,-1.6 34.9,-1.8 0.3,-0.1 0.6,-0.1 1,-0.1 0.9,0 1.8,-0.1 2.7,-0.1 0.8,0 1.7,-0.1 2.5,-0.1 6.1,-0.2 13,-0.5 21.7,-1.3 2.5,-0.2 5.2,-0.4 8.1,-0.7 4.3,-0.4 8.1,-0.5 11.3,-0.4 0.1,-0.1 0.3,-0.1 0.4,0 31.1,1 18,23.2 47.5,33.1 32.7,10.8 45.7,-6.6 45.7,-6.6 0,0 -20,-8.5 -33.3,-30.3 -3.2,-5.1 -5.9,-11 -8,-17.6 -10.9,-34.8 -28.3,-78.3 -34.9,-126.2 -6.5,-47.9 -63.1,-78.4 -75.1,-115.4 -12,-37 -40.3,13 -40.3,65.3 0,52.2 26.2,82.7 8.7,117.6 -17.4,34.8 -65.3,74 -65.3,74 0,0 15.3,-58.8 4.4,-124.1 -10.9,-65.3 -39.2,-132.8 -4.4,-178.5 34.9,-45.8 100.2,-80.6 80.6,-124.1 -19.6,-43.6 -58.8,-61 -82.7,-58.8 -24,2.2 -75.7,-4.4 -52,-61 23.7,-56.6 38.9,-56.6 54.1,-60.9 15.3,-4.4 -8.7,-43.6 2.2,-61 10.9,-17.4 21.8,-54.4 15.3,-65.3 -6.6,-10.9 0,-15.3 37,50.1 37,65.3 79.7,41.3 88.8,104.5 9.1,63.1 12.4,128.4 17.3,148 4.9,19.6 -9.3,6.5 29.4,2.2 38.6,-4.4 103.8,-2.2 121.3,15.2 17.5,17.4 -15.2,28.3 -36.9,132.8 -21.8,104.5 -47.9,202.5 -13.1,254.8 5.1,7.7 11.6,15.7 18.9,23.8 37,-2.8 73.1,-5.7 108,-8.7 -4.2,-30.9 -11.4,-61.2 -23.5,-79.4 -32.7,-49 0,-192.6 0,-192.6 0,0 62.1,45.7 84.9,143.6 10.4,44.5 35.6,85.6 60,117.2 21.2,-2.1 41.8,-4.2 61.8,-6.3 0.6,-31.5 -0.1,-72.7 -4.2,-120.7
      
      
      
      
M 4305.29,2840.62 c 4.6,3.64
 6.58,-66.95 19.64,-88.18 13.07,-21.22 29.84,-29.39 51.66,-24.49 21.82,4.9 39.78,11.43 39.78,11.43 0,0 12.88,-29.39 -16.42,-66.94 -29.3,-37.56 -43.99,-27.76 -65.22,-101.24 -21.23,-73.48 -70.21,-164.92 -80.01,-209 -9.79,-44.09 -24.49,-111.04 -88.17,-120.83 -63.68,-9.8 -150.22,-4.9 -177.98,22.86 -27.76,27.75 -31.02,68.58 -78.38,50.61 -47.35,-17.96 -42.45,-31.02 -117.56,-62.04 -75.11,-31.03 -127.36,-50.09 -169.82,-16.07 -42.45,34.03 -89.8,96.08 -89.8,132 0,35.92 17.96,52.25 0,70.21 -17.96,17.96 -37.56,40.82 -32.66,52.25 4.9,11.43 81.64,68.58 127.36,78.38 45.72,9.79 93.07,-4.9 161.65,29.39 68.58,34.29 124.1,39.19 129,42.45 4.9,3.27 4.9,24.49 -34.29,29.39 -39.19,4.9 -73.48,4.9 -119.2,-26.12 -45.72,-31.03 -53.88,-42.46 -88.17,-47.36 -34.29,-4.89 -94.71,-26.12 -94.71,-26.12 0,0 0,13.06 76.75,53.88 76.74,40.82 171.44,73.48 204.1,73.48 32.66,0 73.89,26.13 81.03,26.13 7.14,0 99.78,-16.33 150.62,-44.09 50.83,-27.76 70.43,-47.35 129.21,-58.78 58.78,-11.43 91.07,11.43 96.15,21.22 5.08,9.8 14.79,32.66 -14.56,27.76 -29.34,-4.9 -63.63,-35.92 -60.36,-9.79 3.26,26.12 19.49,147.26 60.36,179.61
 
 
 M4961.74,4435.36 c 0,0 -15.24,-52.25 -15.24,-74.02 0,-21.78 -15.24,-67.5 -17.42,-93.62 -2.17,-26.13 -21.77,-67.49 -21.77,-67.49 0,0 41.37,19.59 54.43,58.78 13.06,39.19 -4.35,78.38 0,104.5 4.36,26.13 0,71.85 0,71.85
 
 M4135.52,2541.81 c 0.74,5.84 70.22,-4.9 83.28,-80.01 0,0 -88.17,40.82 -83.28,80.01
 
 
 M4738.04,3939.52 c 0,0 -31.02,-58.78 -53.88,-80.01 -22.86,-21.23 -44.09,-35.92 -78.38,-39.19 -34.29,-3.26 -81.64,-45.72 -101.23,-48.98 -19.6,-3.27 26.12,-27.76 76.74,0 50.62,27.75 50.62,13.06 88.17,39.18 37.56,26.13 78.38,73.48 68.58,129
 
 M4760.9,3828.49 c 0,16.32 -75.11,-231.87 -122.46,-292.28 0,0 122.46,130.62 122.46,292.28
 
 M4249.82,4045.78 c 0,0 -34.29,-45.85 -21.22,-80.14 13.06,-34.29 53.88,-75.11 66.94,-99.6 13.07,-24.49 13.07,-68.58 0,-96.34 -13.06,-27.75 -52.25,-52.25 -44.08,-60.41 8.16,-8.17 83.27,3.26 101.23,0 17.96,-3.27 58.78,-3 58.78,-3 0,0 -4.45,-39.46 -34.88,-47.62 -30.43,-8.16 -69.62,4.9 -79.41,9.8 -9.8,4.9 -40.83,7.82 -40.83,-12.42 0,-20.24 21.53,-67.59 62.2,-62.69 40.67,4.9 89.66,3.26 120.68,32.65 31.03,29.39 71.85,56.72 71.85,56.72 0,0 -16.33,-53.45 -17.96,-59.98 -1.64,-6.53 -9.8,-40.82 -76.75,-68.58 0,0 57.15,-8.17 107.77,83.27 50.62,91.44 155.12,120.8 155.12,120.8 0,0 11.43,-16.29 -11.43,-53.85 -22.86,-37.56 -50.62,-53.88 -81.64,-86.54 -31.03,-32.66 -46.83,-70.21 -86.28,-94.71 -39.45,-24.49 -135.79,-63.68 -166.81,-57.14 -31.03,6.53 -50.62,14.69 -83.28,14.69 -32.65,0 -68.58,-6.53 -63.68,24.49 4.9,31.03 44.09,45.72 65.32,45.72 21.22,0 35.92,8.17 16.33,22.86 -19.6,14.7 -55.52,21.23 -66.95,19.6 -11.43,-1.64 -29.39,9.79 -57.15,-3.27 -27.76,-13.06 -93.07,-53.88 -93.07,-53.88 0,0 13.06,58.78 21.22,71.84 8.17,13.07 53.89,42.46 53.89,42.46 0,0 -60.42,-9.8 -75.11,-42.46 0,0 11.43,109.4 55.51,132.26 0,0 -70.21,-35.92 -99.6,-146.95 -29.39,-111.04 -55.52,-104.51 -55.52,-104.51 0,0 40.83,68.58 27.76,143.7 -13.06,75.11 31.03,122.98 31.03,122.98 0,0 -58.79,-20.12 -58.79,-36.44 0,0 11.43,40.82 45.72,47.35 0,0 -47.35,6.44 -52.25,62.82 -4.9,56.37 21.23,142.92 21.23,142.92 0,0 40.82,-29.4 60.41,-81.65 19.6,-52.25 31.03,-101.23 50.62,-112.66 19.6,-11.43 89.81,-58.78 94.71,-66.95 4.9,-8.16 40.82,-14.69 40.82,-14.69 0,0 -13.06,45.72 19.59,71.84 32.66,26.13 47.35,48.95 24.49,80.81 -22.85,31.86 -102.86,134.99 -6.53,196.9
 
 
 M4096.34,3310.88 c 0,0 13.06,1.63 40.82,39.18 27.76,37.56 34.29,86.54 57.15,65.32 22.86,-21.23 55.51,-1.39 55.51,-49.68 0,-48.29 -22.86,-46.66 0,-76.05 22.86,-29.39 42.46,-50.62 42.46,-50.62 0,0 -3.27,-21.23 -21.23,-32.66 -17.96,-11.43 -27.76,9.8 -31.02,-16.32 -3.27,-26.13 -14.7,-63.69 -14.7,-63.69 0,0 14.7,-16.32 40.82,16.33 26.13,32.66 34.29,35.93 62.05,63.68 27.76,27.76 37.56,37.56 68.58,37.56 31.02,0 114.3,6.53 119.2,6.53 4.89,0 -138.79,-0.57 -155.12,20.94 -16.33,21.51 -30.41,99.89 -47.87,135.81 -17.45,35.93 -15.81,60.6 -66.43,58.06 -50.62,-2.54 -168.18,-31.93 -150.22,-154.39
 
 M4151.85,3501.92 c 0,0 -37.55,-60.42 -71.84,-96.34 -34.29,-35.92 -55.52,-122.46 -55.52,-122.46 0,0 -45.72,75.11 0,117.56 45.72,42.46 127.36,101.24 127.36,101.24
 
 M4244.93,3268.42 c 0,-4.9 -16.33,-52.25 -29.4,-71.84 -13.06,-19.6 -13.06,-35.93 -32.65,-66.95 -19.6,-31.02 -47.36,-55.52 -47.36,-27.76 0,27.76 11.43,53.2 22.86,77.22 11.43,24.02 24.5,45.25 39.19,48.51 14.7,3.27 47.36,40.82 47.36,40.82
 
 M4480.05,3167.19 c -4.89,0 -63.68,-34.29 -83.27,-52.25 -19.59,-17.97 -22.86,-4.9 -34.29,-71.85 -11.43,-66.95 -39.19,-93.07 -42.45,-106.13 -3.27,-13.07 37.55,-84.91 37.55,-84.91 0,0 -4.46,24.49 19,93.07 23.45,68.58 33.25,130.89 56.11,144.64 22.86,13.75 47.35,77.43 47.35,77.43
 
 M3554.23,2447.1 c 8.6,11.11 40.83,55.52 62.05,42.46 21.23,-13.07 39.19,-44.96 57.15,-20.03 17.96,24.93 8.17,54.63 40.82,60.19 32.66,5.56 55.52,-21.13 83.28,13.44 27.76,34.57 83.27,44.37 91.44,32.94 8.16,-11.43 19.59,27.76 21.22,-24.49 1.64,-52.26 -11.43,-99.61 -32.65,-104.51 -21.23,-4.89 -70.22,6.54 -94.71,0 -24.49,-6.53 -4.9,24.5 -44.08,14.7 -39.19,-9.8 -63.69,-14.7 -102.87,-32.66 -39.19,-17.96 -68.58,-27.76 -68.58,-27.76 0,0 -24.86,30.48 -13.07,45.72
 
 M 4160.48,3791.01 c -4.7,2.2 -156.3,76 -156.3,239.4 0,61 56.6,89.3 73.8,158.9 17.3,69.7 4.2,63.2 -24.1,185.1 -20.1,86.5 -26.8,121.5 -9.7,164 9.5,0.1 19,0.2 28.5,0.2 -12.8,-38.4 -32.4,-63.5 -7.9,-116.3 28.3,-61 78.4,-102.3 60.9,-172 -17.4,-69.7 -43.5,-89.3 -56.6,-163.3 -13,-74 -36.6,-84.9 8.9,-165.5 44.2,-78 80.3,-127.4 82.5,-130.5"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```